# Are there any Java runtime exploring tools?

Tags: java, debugging, runtime

Are there any Java runtime exploring tools? I mean the tools allowing to invoke concrete objects' methods in the running application (to check the correct behavior). It would be nice if I could substitute the object with another object of this type also, may be instantiated from sketch or deserialized from some source. As I looked, usual debuggers are limited in this possibilities, but I don`t pretend to the fact I`ve checked all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest bytecode manipulation frameworks like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) or [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would use basic [jUnit](http://www.junit.org/) and [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) for creating different input mock objects to check the behavior of your class in different situations.  Then in the end you have a nice set of unit tests to maintain your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this at a higher level than direct bytecode manipulation using AOP tools such as AspectJ. Here are a couple of pointers:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-aspectj2/
- http://danielroop.com/blog/2007/10/04/jmock-and-aspectj/